# Braintree with Cordova for purchases in app for feature upgrades

Tags: android, cordova, paypal, braintree

I use Cordova for our app development.  We are on Android.  We have been looking into several different ways to make purchases of our products and services.  We would like to make it possible to purchase directly from the app that would allow our equipment to be feature modifiable in the field.

Note:  I know that there is a released plugin for PayPal found here: [PayPal-Cordova-Plugin](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin).  What I need to know is if the Javascript SDK and drop in UI from the Braintree project has been used with Cordova.  Are there examples of it's use?

Rather, if have you implemented the Braintree client server using Cordova and Android, where did you start and did it work out?

I have tried to include the client-side functionality:

```
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>
<script>
  braintree.setup("CLIENT-TOKEN-FROM-SERVER", "<integration>", options);
</script>
```

I currently don't have a server-side to setup in order to test the functionality.  I would like to know if I start down this path if it will be worth my time and if anyone else has tried to implement the code using Cordova.

Comment: Asking for examples isn't really appropriate on Stack Overflow, rather it's for specific, technical questions. That said, it looks like the PayPal plugin is a thin wrapper around their Android library; it doesn't use their JavaScript library. You should be able to do the same thing with the Braintree Android library but I don't know of any examples.

Comment: I wasn't asking for a post of an example just if there are examples and where one might find how one might go about implementing the functions using Cordova.  The Braintree group is asking for questions that will spur aid in finding details that can't be found elsewhere.  Currently in all my searches there are no instances of someone saying that you would be able to use Cordova thus this question to the good people of Stack Overflow to know if anyone has accomplished this feat and how they got started.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To start I know this response might be really late, although I will still give it, since I looked for this for a long time myself.

To start off the Cordova library from Braintree is not worth investigating. I spent more than 40 hours fiddling with it and didn't find any really useful answers anywhere on the web.

The easy solution is to implement an in-app browser in Cordova, and link it to an online website.
 https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

which can be added by the command: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`

There you can use the very handy and easy to configure drop-in UI from Braintree.

The first problems that arose to me were the iframe Braintree uses for the Cordova implementation, I tested this on android and it did work fine and open everything well.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
    var ref = window.open('XXX/payment.php', 'location=yes');
}
```

and on the server you can just use js/php to make everything work.

Comment: I have the same problem, that the PayPal auth flow iFrame is blank. Could you explain the code part of your answer?

Comment: I added an eventlistener to the page in javascript. Once the page is loaded, it will open the inappbrowser-plugin. 
In this plugin I load the webpage containing my payment form.

This web page only contains the dropin UI which you can easily implement from the documentation braintree provides.
If you can't figure it out exactly I might be able to help you.

Comment: @mitchken I am facing the same problem as `obiwahn`, it does work the half way but then the page goes blank

Comment: I am sorry, I implemented it this way. But that project is done and not in my hands anymore. I'm sorry but i won't be able to help you.

Comment: We are writing  an open source capacitor plugin wrapper, for the Braintree IOS sdk and android  sdk. This is specifically  to support Apple Pay and Google pay, besides  accepting credit cards, in a marketplace setup. Will soon reply to this question with details on our solution.